# 『トピックモデルによる統計的潜在意味解析』の2.2節のp(x_i | π)=Multi(x_i | π)の成立理由

Tags: 機械学習

とてもピンポイントな質問で申し訳ありませんが、
『トピックモデルによる統計的潜在意味解析』（奥村学 監修、佐藤一誠 著）の
2.2節の式(2.3)の前の文章に以下が書かれており、私には飛躍的で理解できません。

> `p(x_i=k | π)=Multi(n_k=1 | π, 1)`と考えられるため、
>   これを`p(x_i | π)=Multi(x_i | π)`と表記する。

ここで、K個の目を持ついびつなサイコロを想定しており、

1. kの目が出る確率は`π_k`です。
2. `x_i=k`により、i回目の試行でkが出ることを表します。
3. n回の独立した試行において、`n_k`はkの目が出る回数を表します。

1行目は理解できますが、それによってなぜ2行目が成立するのかが分かりません。
多項分布は`Multi(目が出る回数 | 目の出る確率, 試行回数)`で書くと思っていましたが、
`x_i`はどう見ても「回数」ではないし、試行回数も書かれていません。

超有名本なのでどなたか読破した方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただきたいです。
以上、宜しくお願い致します。